# C#: Read data and add it to a list

Tags: c#

Please help me read data from a reader and insert it to a list. Reader returns 1 row with 100 columns. All are short.

```
  querysting = "select * from db2prod.questions where key_id =" + app.key_id;
  DB2cmd = new odbccommand(querystring,DBConn,DBtrans)
  DB2cmd.Commandtype = Commandtype.text
  DB2Rdr = DB2cmd.ExecuteReader;
   if(DB2Rdr.hasrows = true)
    {
      DB2Rdr.read();
      /* insert into the list
      /* compare if the 1st,3rd,5th,7th position is not null then insert in 
       a new table whose format is |key_idQues | Ans*/
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, could you show us some code you have tried so far ?

Comment: Suggest you google tutorial on basic ADO.NET

Comment: Why you store all 100 questions in columns instead of separate records in a related table?

Comment: it is an old table and is designed that way.

Comment: `if(DB2Rdr.hasrows = true)`  ---> `if(DB2Rdr.hasrows == true)`

Comment: `DB2Rdr = DB2cmd.ExecuteReader;`  ---> `DB2Rdr = DB2cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it...
(for MSSQL, but apart from the connection the principal is the same)

```
private List<short> SQLColumnsToList()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(/*Your connection string here*/))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from db2prod.questions where key_id = @keyID";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("keyID", /*Your ID here*/);

            conn.Open();
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var list = new List<short>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; ++i)
                        list.Add(rdr.GetInt16(i));
                    return list;
                }
                throw new Exception("No row found");
            }
        }
    }
```